# How to make the wrap text around the image?

Tags: graphics, two-column

How to make the wrap text around the image, as in this example?
There are no restrictions. I can use any options

[image]

Comment: What restrictions do you have in terms of the document that should contain this kind of wrapping? Ideally we'd like to see some effort from your end, typically provided in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There are no restrictions. I can use any options

Comment: Which part of the document are you referring to as an image? What I see is a table `Рис.3` that the text wraps around, and a chart `Рис.9` that it does not wrap around. Our terminology is probably different.

Comment: If you're using a two-column document, then why not just place the image at the top of the two columns?

Comment: I mean the second picture (diagram). Because I need to do so, as in the example

Comment: But the text does not wrap around that. You can just use the two-column `figure` format, can't you, as Werner suggested?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand well your problem, you should use the `cuted` package (from the `sttools` bundle)  and its `strip` environment. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{cuted, xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx, caption, threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\textsf{\color{red} Figure appelée ici : }

\begin{strip}\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = off}
\begin{measuredfigure}%[H]
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{Piero_di_Cosimo_1}
\caption[]{The Death of Procris (ca 1500)}
\end{measuredfigure}
\end{strip}
\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]